# Using channels to pass data from outputStream to bytebuffer

Tags: java, nio, bytebuffer, channel

Is there a way to write data to an OutputStream object which is connected to a channel, and this channel will pass the data to a bytebuffer (preferably, direct bytebuffer)?

I have a situation where a third party function can write its output to an outputStream. I want to be able to write this data to a bytebuffer using channels.

Is it possible?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post your channel code?

Comment: I don't have any channel yet. I'm planning to add one to be able to read data which was written to outputStream and pass it to byteBuffer

Comment: Then you only really need a `ByteBuffer` and not a channel, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create a class that `extends OutputStream` since this only requires *one* method to be implemented. Sample, untested code:

```
public final class ByteBufferOutputStream
    extends OutputStream
{
    private final ByteBuffer buf;

    public ByteBufferOutputStream(final int size)
    {
        buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(size);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(final int b)
        throws IOException
    {
        if (buf.remaining() == 0)
            throw new IOException("buffer is full");
        buf.put((byte) (b & 0xff));
    }
}
```

Then just pass an instance of that class to your API. You'll also probably want to override the other `write` methods since `ByteBuffer` has dedicated methods to write byte arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks that the function will write a single byte on each call. Any idea how to improve the efficiency of this function?

Comment: Well, after the code, I have added further text: you can overwrite the _other_ `.write()` methods